# System.Array. does not contain a definition for "ToList"

Tags: .net-3.5, c#-3.0

I'm getting the above error on the ToList() line of the code below

```
if (emailReplyTo != null)
{
  System.Collections.Generic.List<String> replyto
    = emailReplyTo
    // Strip uneccessary spaces
    .Replace(", ", ",")
    .Split(',')
    .ToList();

  request.WithReplyToAddresses(emailReplyTo);
}
```

I have included `using System.Collections;` at the top of my file.
The target framework is 3.5, so why is this causing an error?

Comment: If someone is having the same issue, Take a deep look at `Output` window. Because `Error` window might be misleading sometimes.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) method you are looking for is an extension method. Try adding this `using` directive to the top of your file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

By adding this `using` directive you are indicating to the compiler that any extension methods in that namespace should be imported. It's kind of a shame that there isn't more help from Visual Studio around importing extension methods (ReSharper does this rather nicely).

Comment: Nice. I'm a little surprised you can't just right click on this in VisualStudio and find a "resolve ..." option.

Answer (score 31):

In case someone stumbles on this questions after googling...

I had the exact same problem in *Razor views* and adding `using System.Linq` at the top didn't help.

What did help is calling `.Cast()` before using Linq extension methods:

```
myArrayVariable.Cast<SomeClass>().ToList() //ok, NOW ToList works fine
```

Comment: Same problem and solution in dotnet 4.5 ordinary unit test code. I have not checked why.

Comment: Correct. It has to be done when working with enums for instance. Getting a list of MyEnumType names as strings: System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnumType)).Cast<MyEnumType>().Select(v=>v.ToString()).ToList();

Answer (score 14):

You can also do this without .toList, saves including an entire library for no real reason.

new List(array)

Comment: That was a huge help! Don't forget the <T>, though: new List<T>(array);

Answer (score 9):

ToList() is an extension method. Maybe you're missing the

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 6):

This is simply because `ArrayList` does not expose a method named `ToList`.

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) for a table view of the members available to you.

As explained by others, you may access this *extension* method by importing the Linq library:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Also, [see this link](http://schleichermann.wordpress.com/2009/11/11/c-arraylist-tolist-extension-method/) for a custom implementation of such, should you desire to implement one.

Comment: You mean `Array`, not `ArrayList` …

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Well, now I do. ;) Could have sworn I read `ArrayList` in the title, but can't see any edits so I must be mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the Enumerable extension methods aren't available.

You need to add "using System.Linq"

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 var lst = ((IEnumerable<XElement>)doc.Element("cards").Elements("card")).ToList();
```

My initial result was simply a dynamic.  The .Cast() method gave me the same error as ToList() but this did the trick.