# old ASP.NET: rotate/shuffle/randomize a variable for each pageview or each user by ipv4

Tags: c#, asp.net

We try to hotfix an old ASP.NET project. only got PHP experience yet.

Instead of the below, the 'Key' needs to be randomly selected from a list so that each "key" is used about equally often.

```
string sKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"];
```

(Referring to the `web.config` file.)

For example 10000 people use the site per day, 20000 pageviews.
now there are 20 keys* and each should be used for approximately 500 users** 
or for approximately 1000 pageviews**.

*(Currently in a static file, "keys.txt", one key per line)

**(users can only be distinguished by their IPv4s, but total random is ok too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by creating a random number withing the range of the number of keys and use the one that was randomly selected.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Linq;

//list to hold the keys
List<string> keys = new List<string>();

//dummy data
keys = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(i => "Key_" + i).ToList();

//or read the file from disk
string path = Server.MapPath("keys.txt");
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    keys = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
}

//create a random number and select the key
Random rnd = new Random();
string key = keys[rnd.Next(0, keys.Count)];
```

Comment: Maybe you need `HttpContext.Current.Server`. And `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Added all the `using` you need.

Comment: The reference should be there by default in Visual Studio. But if not add a reference to it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019#:~:targetText=A%20reference%20is%20essentially%20an,Explorer%20and%20choose%20Add%20Reference.

Comment: thanks, 0 Projects in "Solution Explorer", hence editing web.config  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37695330

Comment: back to CS0117: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'  
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/57272803       (also this, but i we dont need dummy data CS0117: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' – )

Comment: got it working through this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6904455
edited your answer. thanks!